# MATLAB GUI doesn't work (but it does!)

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

Whenever I access my gui via typing *guide untitled* in command line and pushing the green arrow called *Run Figure* it **does** work perfectly.

But when I try to run it simply by clicking *untitled.fig* in the sidebar I get some errors as I put some values and click a button to calculate.

```
Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

Error in untitled>oblicz_Callback (line 81)
v = get(handles.wprowadz, 'String');

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
    feval(varargin{:});

Error in untitled (line 42)
gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in @(hObject,eventdata)untitled('oblicz_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're not supposed to open a GUI via the *.fig file, but via the associated *.m file, which contains the code to correctly open the *.fig file, with all the associated callbacks.

So if you want to run your GUI, either open the *.fig file through GUIDE as you currently do, or run the corresponding *.m file.

Comment: By simply clicking on the *.fig file, the callbacks aren't defined, which is why an error is generated when you press the button on the GUI.